# Google Analytics UserID Tracking Code

Tags: google-analytics

I'm setting up UserID tracking in Google Analytics. [Google's documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/user-id) displays this piece of code to push UserIDs into analytics:

```
ga('create', 'UA-XXXX-Y', { 'userId': 'USER_ID' });
ga('send', 'pageview');
```

However, when I'm in my Google Analytic's settings area, it displays the following piece of code to include UserIDs.

```
ga(‘set’, ‘&uid’, {{USER_ID}}); // Set the user ID using signed-in user_id.
```

What is the difference between set and create? Do they both achieve the same result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both of them should work. Including the user id in the 'create' call includes setting it as well.

```
ga('create', 'UA-XXXX-Y', {'userId': 'USER_ID'});
ga('send', 'pageview');
```

is equivalent to

```
ga('create', 'UA-XXXX-Y');
ga('set', '&uid', {{USER_ID}}); // Set the user ID using signed-in user_id.
ga('send', 'pageview');
```

If you do copy and paste provided in GA, then you will need to change the smart quotes to straight quotes, because smart quotes will break GA.